# how to refresh updatePanel with asp.net Timer control only once ?

Tags: asp.net, timer

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="100" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                   // my code is here
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePane>
```

above code refresh update panel in the period time.

Comment: Not able to make out anything from this code? Can you please brief the requirement or put some more code?

Comment: Welcome Saeed - please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [explaining your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should balance the quotes for the value `server` of the `runat` attribute.

Comment: This makes no sense the OnCheckedChanged would trigger either way when the value is updated from javascript.